# How to get rid of specific tsserver errors with nvim native lsp?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vim, neovim

I just started working on an electron project and I am using the neovim native lsp. I have tsserver correctly installed and the language seems to work well, however I am getting an error "File is a CommonJS module; it may be converted to an ES6 module" which I would like to ignore. I'm relatively new to neovim and would really appreciate a fix for this.